# I'm using Powershell to speak to the Microsoft Graph API. However, my JSON doesn't work and I have no idea why. Can someone help me?

Tags: json, powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to add compliance policies to Intune using the Graph API. However, when I try to use it it says "Provided JSON isn't in valid JSON format" and "Invalid JSON primitive: True".

The code I'm using comes from the Microsoft Graph samples (found [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples))

I think it's probably something really simple, but I don't have much experience with Powershell. I can't seem to find it though.

```
$JSON_Android = @"

    {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.androidCompliancePolicy",
    "displayName": "Google_Android_Device_Compliance_Powershell",
    "passwordRequired": true,
    "passwordMinimumLength": 5,
    "passwordRequiredType": "numeric",
    "passwordMinutesOfInactivityBeforeLock": 15,
    "passwordExpirationDays": null,
    "passwordPreviousPasswordBlockCount": 5,
    "securityPreventsInstallAppsFromUnknownSource": true,
    "securityDisableUsbDebugging": false,
    "requireAppVerify": false,
    "deviceThreatProtectionEnabled": false,
    "deviceThreatProtectionRequiredSecurityLevel": "unavailable",
    "securityBlockJailbrokenDevices": true,
    "osMinimumVersion": null,
    "osMaximumVersion": null,
    "minAndroidSecurityPatchLevel": null,
    "storageRequireEncryption": true
    "securityRequireSafetyNetAttestationBasicIntegrity": false,
    "securityRequireSafetyNetAttestationCertifiedDevice": false,
    "securityRequireGooglePlayServices": false,
    "securityRequireUpToDateSecurityProviders": false,
    "securityRequireCompanyPortalAppIntegrity": true
    }

"@


####################################################

$JSON_iOS = @"

  {
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.iosCompliancePolicy",
  "displayName": "Apple_iOS_Device_Compliance_Powershell",
  "passCodeBlockSimple": true,
  "passcodeExpirationDays": null,
  "passcodeMinimumLength": 5,
  "passcodeMinutesOfInactivityBeforeLock" 15,
  "passcodePreviousPasscodeBlockCount": 5,
  "passcodeMinimumCharacterSetCount": null,
  "passcodeRequiredType": "numeric",
  "passcodeRequired": true,
  "osMinimumVersion": null,
  "osMaximumVersion": null,
  "securityBlockJailbrokenDevices": true,
  "deviceThreatProtectionEnabled": false,
  "deviceThreatProtectionRequiredSecurityLevel": "unavailable",
  "managedEmailProfileRequired": false
  }

"@

####################################################

$JSON_Windows10 = @"

    {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.windows10MobileCompliancePolicy",
    "displayName": "Microsoft_Windows_Device_Compliance_Powershell"
    "passwordRequired": true,
    "passwordBlockSimple": false,
    "passwordMinimumLength": 5,
    "passwordMinimumCharacterSetCount": null,
    "passwordRequiredType": "numeric",
    "passwordRequiredToUnlockFromIdle": false,
    "passwordExpirationDays": null,
    "passwordPreviousPasswordBlockCount": 5,
    "passwordMinutesOfInactivityBeforeLock": 15,
    "requireHealthyDeviceReport": false,
    "osMinimumVersion": null,
    "osMaximumVersion": null,
    "mobileOsMinimumVersion": null,
    "mobileOsMaximumVersion": null,
    "earlyLaunchAntiMalwareDriverEnabled": false,
    "bitLockerEnabled": false,
    "secureBootEnabled": false,
    "codeIntegrityEnabled": false,
    "storageRequireEncryption": true,
    "activeFirewallRequired": false,
    "uacRequired": false,
    "validOperatingSystemBuildRanges": false
    }

"@
```

Comment: The fault seems to be in the Android JSON, since that's where it stops.

Comment: "I'm using Powershell to speak to the Microsoft Graph API. However, my JSON doesn't work and I have no idea why." is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `True` and `False` values should be `true` and `false` respectively; note the case difference.

Comment: I've fixed that and several indentation problems. The error it gives is different this time, so that seems to have solved something at least.

Comment: Lol! I had that problem a while back. I just remember thinking as I was doing it, this can't possibly be the issue, and it was. Parsers!

Comment: It's more that almost all other programming languages are case-sensitive and PowerShell follows the *Microsoft Way* of case insensitivity even down to function, variable names, and keywords. `$true -eq $TRUE -eq $TrUe`

Answer (score 1):

"storageRequireEncryption": true

In the first JSON, there should be a comma after that.